# What to Update on MainQueue while running Async Call

Tags: swift, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, grand-central-dispatch

I send some info to Firebase and 5 things can happen in the callback if successful or 3 things can happen if unsuccessful:

**If successful:**

1. the activity indicator is dismissed
2. a class level variable with the date updates
3. an alert appears with a message that includes that variable
4. a push is performed to another vc
5. the sendButton is enabled again (it's disabled once they press it)

**If UnSuccessful:**

1. the activity indicator is dismissed
2. an alert appears with a message that says it's unsuccessful
3. the sendButton is enabled again (it's disabled once they press it)

When I tried to put the navigationController?.pushViewController on the mainQueue there was always problems with it specifically it didn't always perform.

```
//caused problems
DispatchQueue.main.async {
         navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: false)
            }
```

Once I took it off and left it in the background it ran perfectly fine. I know I should update the alert but what about the class level variable that the alert uses and dismissing activity indicator?

Firebase Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak fileprivate var sendButton: UIButton!

let date = Date() //formatted in viewDidLoad
var todaysDate = ""
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView() //formatted in viewDidLoad

@IBAction fileprivate func sendButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){

sendButton.isEnabled = false
view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

//dict has some values

nextVCRef?.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: {
            (error, ref) in

            if error != nil{

              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.activityIndicator.removeFromSuperView
                self.alertError()
                self.sendButton.isEnabled = true//i normally would put this is the alertError action but for clarity i put it here
              }
              return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.todaysDate = self.date
                self.alertSuccessful()//everything happens in the function
            }
        })
}

fileprivate alertSuccessful(){
        self.activityIndicator!.removeFromSuperView
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Thank You!", message: "Today's date is \(self.todaysDate).", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
            (action) in
            self.sendButton.isEnabled = true
            _ = self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: false)
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

fileprivate alertError(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Unknown Error!", message: "There was an error. Try again.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The question is between the variable being set, activity indicator being dismissed, the alert appearing, sendButton being re-enabled, and a push being performed, what **should** and **shouldn't** be on the main queue?

Btw I didn't need to update the date variable in the background but in another scenario I might pull some info from Firebase and the variable would be updated in the callback. I didn't include that code and used this instead because the main point is should the class variable get updated on the mainqueue in the background thread?

Comment: Everything regarding UI must be on the main queue.

Comment: @shallowThought even the variable and the nav push (they're not on the actual ui)?

Comment: `UINavigationController` pushes an `UIViewController`. Both have "UI" in there name. They could not be more "on the actual ui".

Comment: @shallowThought ahhhhhhhhhhh, now that was insightful. I never thought about them beginning with "UI". Thanks! Why do you think I was having problems when i was pushing the nav on the main queue but all the problems stopped once I took it off?

Comment: By the way, Firebase *completion blocks* are always called on the *main queue* so you don't need to wrap those calls in `DispatchQueue.main` at all :-)

Comment: @PauloMattos thanks! I never knew that. 

Comment: @LanceSamaria haha... try to imagine the resulting chaos if that wasn't the case... :-)

Comment: @Paulo Mattos makes sense. Outside of my nav push not working i always wondered why i never had any other weird problems. I chalked it up as me being the only user vs having a bunch of users. I'm glad they did it that way.  I can focus on other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @shallowThought noted in the comments below the answer, anything that has a prefix of `UI` as in `UINavigationController` or `UIView` or `UIActivityIndicator` or `UIButton` are are all `user interface` objects and should be on the mainQueue. The mainQueue is specifically for user interface objects or the abbreviation `UI` objects. Something very easy to remember thanks to him :) The variables should be updated on it too.

The beauty of Firebase which I didn't know as @Paulo Mattos noted in the comments is that the Firebase completion blocks all happen on the mainQueue so it alleviates the hassle of having to add DispatchQueue.main.asyc{}

Upvote their comments!